# Copying last cell in a column and offsetting by 1

Tags: excel, vba

i have a code that copies an array of values from 1 sheet and pastes it in another now i want to offst the last populated row by 1 and delete the original row ie if the last row were L12:(entire row) it is pasted to L13 and row L12 is left empty.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Pivot_WH calculations") 'change name as needed

With ws
   'assumes data is in a "table" format with all data rows in column A and data columns in row 1

   .Range("E2:J7").Copy _
    Worksheets("WH Calc_new").Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)

    .Range("E8:J8").Copy _
    Worksheets("WH Calc_new").Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)

   .Range("A2:A9").Copy _
    Worksheets("WH Calc_new").Range("K" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to Achieve. It is not clear.

Comment: i need to offset the last row in the data i paste each week to make sure the datas symmetric so if theres data in L12 then id need to cut that and paste it in L13.

Comment: You are already offsetting 2 rows by using `.Offset(2)`

Comment: Yes i need to offset the last row by 1 more

Comment: Use `.Offset(3)` instead of `.Offset(2)`

Comment: Ive edited the code so this does what i need the only problem is that there are times when the last row is unpopulated so is there any way to use someother column  to do the X1up

Comment: Then id have to have 2 different codes one using offset(2) and another offset(3)

Answer (score 0):

- The Function at the End will give you the last Row That is actually the last row used in the Worksheet.
- For the offset you can change 2 to 3 or 4 or any other number you want to Offset in `.Offset(Number_Here)`

**Try This:**

```
Sub cdd()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lst As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Pivot_WH calculations") 'change name as needed
lst = LastRow(Worksheets("WH Calc_new"))

With ws

    .Range("E2:J7").Copy Worksheets("WH Calc_new").Range("L" & lst).Offset(2)

    .Range("E8:J8").Copy Worksheets("WH Calc_new").Range("L" & lst).Offset(2)

    .Range("A2:A9").Copy Worksheets("WH Calc_new").Range("K" & lst).Offset(2)

End With

End Sub
Function LastRow(Sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = Sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=Sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Pls check this, its a better desc of what im trying to do (https://imgur.com/a/8m5Mj2F)

Comment: @KarthikApadodharanan .. Please include an Image of Before and after.

Comment: Ive added before and after images